# Calculate the projection of $g(x)=\exp(−2x^2)$ onto the subspace $S$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have problem to getting started on this one:

"Let $f_1(x) = \exp(−x^2)$, $f_2(x) = xf_1(x)$, S the subspace of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ spanned by $\{f_1,f_2\}$, and $P$ the projector onto $S$. Find $Pg$, where $g(x) = \exp(−2x^2)$."

Comment: Hint: use inner product

Comment: like <f_1|g>+<f_2|g> or something? more help =)

Comment: $\langle f_1|g\rangle f_1 +\langle f_2|g\rangle f_2$ assuming that $f_1$ and $f_2$ form an orthonormal basis. Otherwise, you'll need to find an orthogonal basis first, then project as above and then express the elements of the new basis in terms of $f_1$ and $f_2$.

Comment: is it possible to compute Pg more explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle f_1,f_2\rangle_{L^2}&=&\int_\mathbb{R}xf_1^2(x)\,dx=0,\\
\|f_1\|_{L^2}^2&=&\int_\mathbb{R}e^{-2x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}},\\
\|f_2\|_{L^2}^2&=&\int_\mathbb{R}x^2e^{-2x^2}\,dx=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}.
\end{eqnarray}
We set 
$$
\phi_1=\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)^{1/4}f_1,\ \phi_2=\left(\frac{8}{\pi}\right)^{1/4}f_2.
$$
We may choose an orthonormal basis $\{\phi_i\}_{i\ge 3}$ of $S^\perp$ in such a way that $\{\phi_i\}_{i\ge 1}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})=S\oplus S^\perp$. Then 
$$
g=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle g,\phi_i\rangle_{L^2}\phi_i
$$
and
$$
Pg=\alpha_1\phi_1+\alpha_2\phi_2,
$$
with 
$$
\alpha_i=\langle g,\phi_i\rangle_{L^2},\ i=1,2.
$$
Setting $x=\sqrt{\frac23}y$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha_1&=&\langle g,\phi_1\rangle_{L^2}=\|f_1\|_{L^2}^{-1}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{-3x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\frac23}\|f_1\|_{L^2}^{-1}\|f_1\|_{L^2}^2=\sqrt{\frac23}\|f_1\|_{L^2}\\
\alpha_2&=&\langle g,\phi_2\rangle_{L^2}=\|f_2\|_{L^2}^{-1}\int_\mathbb{R}x^2e^{-3x^2}\,dx=\left(\frac23\right)^{3/2}\|f_2\|_{L^2}^{-1}\|f_2\|_{L^2}^2=\left(\frac23\right)^{3/2}\|f_2\|_{L^2}.
\end{eqnarray}
After replacing these values you get that
$$
Pg=\sqrt{\frac23}\left(f_1+\frac23f_2\right).
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Normalize the *vectors* $f_1$ and $f_2$: $$h_i=\frac{f_i}{||f_i||_2}\quad\text{where}\quad ||f_i||_2^2=\int_{\mathbb R}|f_i|^2$$
and since the function $h_1h_2$ is odd then $\displaystyle\langle h_1,h_2\rangle=\int_{\mathbb R}h_1h_2=0$ and then $(h_1,h_2)$ is orthonormal hence

$$Pg=\langle g,h_1\rangle h_1+\langle g,h_2\rangle h_2$$

Comment: You should probably mention that since the product of the two functions is odd, they are orthogonal.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate Pg more explicitly?